# Error obtaining correlation matrix with mixedCor (psych, R)

Tags: r, continuous, psych

I am trying to get a matrix of correlations of a set of continuous(1:8) and polytomous (9:41) variables, using mixedCor from the psych package in R. In order to do this, I created a .csv, including my variables' names in the first row, and the values of these variables for each of the participants in our study (around 350) in the rest of the rows. However, when using the function, I get the following error:

```
r <- mixedCor(df, c=1:8, p=9:41)


Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = colnames(x)) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
Además: Warning messages:
1: In polychoric(data[, p], smooth = smooth, global = global, weight = weight,  :
  The items do not have an equal number of response alternatives, global set to FALSE.
2: In mclapply(seq_len(n), do_one, mc.preschedule = mc.preschedule,  :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
3: In matpLower(x, nvar, gminx, gmaxx, gminy, gmaxy) :
  Something is wrong in polycor 
4: In cor.smooth(mat) :
  I am sorry, there is something seriously wrong with the correlation matrix,
cor.smooth failed to  smooth it because some of the eigen values are NA.  
Are you sure you specified the data correctly?
```

I am using R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) and the previous steps before using mixedCor were:

```
library(psych)
library(psychTools)
mydata <- read.csv ("/myroot/mydata.csv")
df <- data.frame (mydata)
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: It is hard to judge things without any code sample here. You should definitely consider posting the snippet of code that produces the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! Sorry if my description was not clear enough, I'm a beginner in this. Here you can find mixedCor's source code, in case that is what you mean: [link](https://rdrr.io/cran/psych/src/R/mixed.cor.R) I'm not really sure where the issue would be. Hope this helps, please let me know if including other information would help.

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone, I was able to obtain a matrix of correlations without getting an error by adding "correct = 0" when using the function.